# Why hasn't someone proposed a business and accounting Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, off-topic, stackexchange

I need to file taxes soon for my business. I'm reading some accounting textbooks to teach myself the subject. I want to ask questions about it. However, you can't ask accounting theory questions here??

Why hasn't someone made a Stack Exchange site for business and accounting questions? Accounting has got to be popular! Thanks.

Comment: You can go here and propose it yourself: https://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's been proposed twice in the last three years and hasn't gotten the critical mass of contributers (I guess).

Comment: I mod-closed this as it seemed clearly off-topic for here, but since it's got a re-open vote from someone else I'm re-opening. To me it seems like fundamentally a question for the SE network as a whole, not money.meta.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica Thanks. That was my vote to reopen. Considering we frequently get off-topic accounting questions asked at Money, I thought Money meta could have some answer to the question of why there isn't (yet) somewhere in SE for accounting questions. Perhaps we could actively support some new site proposal -- there may be more appetite for it now vs. years ago when it had been previously tried? Just thinking out loud. I'll post an answer with more complete thoughts later.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea to get a site started on Area51 nowadays, you really have to come with a ready-made community, not just create the proposal and hope for the best.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica Imagine: a general "Business Administration" site covering business, management, and accounting *might* be able to get off the ground. Members from Money, The Workplace, Law, Project Management, Economics, and Freelancing could be interested in related topics that are specifically off-topic at the existing sites. Plus, all of those SE sites would have somewhere to migrate a good portion of the questions they would otherwise close as off-topic

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica I'm even wondering if it might be possible for the Freelancing SE to have its scope broadened and be rebranded as a new "Business" site. Freelancing have only had ~50 questions asked in the last 6 months, and they [failed to elect new moderators in their recent election](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318/2020-community-moderator-election-failed-election). Broadening the mandate at Freelancing to cover more general business questions might make it a more viable community.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea all that seems reasonable. If you want to use this question to try to gather that interest I guess it doesn't hurt even if it's not strictly on-topic.

Comment: ... or if "Business Administration" is too ambitious, simply "Small Business", which of course includes self-employment. "Small Business" could capture many of the topics I'm thinking are lacking/underserved by the existing sites (including bookkeeping/accounting) -- and perhaps be a better fit if Freelancing were to consider expanding scope.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea remember you were going to post an answer :-)

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica Yup, will do, thanks. Just taking some time first to do some research and formulate an approach. I don't want to answer "I'm thinking about a way we can address this gap" without an actual plan of some kind.

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica Let me ask one question of the moderators here, though, for you to ponder in the meanwhile: If there were a place in Stack Exchange specifically for small business questions, would *Money* be interested in narrowing existing scope on that front in order to support potential expansion elsewhere in Stack Exchange? Whatever volume of small business-related questions that *Money* currently gets might could make the subject viable elsewhere (e.g. if *Freelancing* were to expand.)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea speaking just for myself I'd be fine if we pushed out the sole trader questions. I guess that's all there would be though? Plus it could be a bit of a fuzzy line.

Comment: Speaking for myself, I'd agree with GS - I'd be happy to dump all of the "small business" questions here and really shouldn't be here anyway, unless they actually are some random person doing their own taxes.  Most of the time they're not that, though, which makes them a poor fit here anyway.  That said, I don't think it should be necessary for us to call them off topic - just to suggest they go to that site if they want more business-related answers.